# ADB commands needed for occulus quest navigation and simulation

Tags: automation, adb

I would like to simulate and navigate the occulus quest device using the adb commands. though there are some adb commands available for the some very specific functions, I need adb commands to specifically simulate and navigate and perform the keypresses of the controller/Joystick. Basically need to know whether, without the controller usage, only by using ADB commands can we navigate or simulate?